# Power Shell script to remove disabled and expired accounts from allusers group in AD

Tags: powershell

I'm about to inherit this script that apparently takes 14 hours to complete. I'm not the best at PowerShell but it seems to me that the first step is to search AD for disabled and/or expired user accounts, then remove them from that group and maybe all groups. Here is the script;

```
$expired_disabled_users = Get-QADGroupMember -Identity allusers -SizeLimit 0 | ?{$_.AccountIsDisabled -eq $true -or $_.AccountIsExpired -eq $true}
$expired_disabled_users | ?{$_.accountisdisabled -eq $true | select Name,whenChanged}
foreach ($user in $expired_disabled_users) {Remove-QADGroupMember -Identity allusers -Member $user}
```

So, I don't have the Quest AD Plugins. How would I speed this script up using regular Module Activedirectory in Powershell? My initial change is something like this, but I don't have a way to test this as I don't have rights in the domain yet;

```
$expired_disabled_users = Get-ADUser -Filter * | ?{$_.AccountIsDisabled -eq $true -or $_.AccountIsExpired -eq $true}
$expired_disabled_users | ?{$_.accountisdisabled -eq $true | select Name,whenChanged}
foreach ($user in $expired_disabled_users) {Remove-QADGroupMember -Identity allusers -Member $user}
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Just a note, using the -Filter argument on Get-ADUser (or most if not all cmdlets) will make the provider filter the request, and increase performance, sometimes dramatically. In this case I think you would see a significant performance increase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to convert the code as is to use the 'activedirectory' module (I don't have the Quest cmdlets) you would get the following.

```
$expired_disabled_users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "allusers" |  Get-Aduser -properties enabled,AccountExpirationDate |
        Where-Object{$_.Enabled -eq $false -or ($_.AccountExpirationDate -is [datetime] -and $_.AccountExpirationDate -lt (Get-Date))}
$expired_disabled_users | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq $false} | select Name
foreach ($user in $expired_disabled_users) {Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "allusers" -Member $user -WhatIf}
```

Now.. that of course would still perform very slow since you are pulling *all* users from Active Directory and then filtering on their account status. I can't find a reference to what *allusers* is in the Quest documentation so I will assume that is a group that exists in your Org. For speed testing I am not going to use group filter  but will show how to filter. I have about 600 users in my AD. I am also not going to remove users but leave that code in with a `-WhatIf` to help simulate processing. Most of the lost time comes from enumerating all the users. Address that and I should think everything else will be ok.

So we can approach this a couple of ways. One of the faster ways to address this would be with an `LDAPFilter` so I will focus on that.

```
$groupDN = (Get-ADGroup "sslvpn_direct_forwards").DistinguishedName
$SecondsSince = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() - (Get-Date "00:00:00 01/01/1601") |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty TotalSeconds
$100NanoSecondIntervals = ($SecondsSince * [Math]::Pow(10, 7)).ToString("0")

$ldapFilter = "(&(memberof=$groupDN)(|(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(&(!(accountExpires=0))(accountExpires<=$100NanoSecondIntervals))))"

Get-Aduser -LDAPFilter $ldapFilter
```

Some explanation

1. `$groupDN` is the `distunguishedName` of the group we are working with. LDAP queries for MemberOf use the DN so we use `Get-AdGroup` to capture that value.
2. Know that `$100NanoSecondIntervals` is the calculation of 100 nanoseconds intervals since "12:00 AM January 1, 1601". Slightly more detail can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
3. The `$ldapfilter` itself is broken up in 4 parts. User needs to be a group member of a certain group and the account has to at least be disabled or expired.

   - (memberof=$groupDN) match the group we are looking for. Resulting users have to be a member of this group
   - (userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2) this just means that the UserAccountControll bit for Enabled is not set ( think I have that explanation right).
   - (!(accountExpires=0))(accountExpires<=$100NanoSecondIntervals) is explained by an account having an expiry value set and the accompanying date occurred in the past..... an expired account

**Show Down**

I cant accurately measure the command in your question for reasons I previously mentioned but I should be able to get a good idea of how they stack up against eachother for the primary query of users.

```
1..20 | %{
    Measure-Command{
        Get-Aduser -filter * -properties enabled,AccountExpirationDate  | Where-Object{$_.Enabled -eq $false -or ($_.AccountExpirationDate -is [datetime] -and $_.AccountExpirationDate -lt (Get-Date))} 
    }
}| Select -Expand TotalSeconds | Measure-Object -Sum 

1..20 | %{
    Measure-Command{
        Get-Aduser -LDAPFilter $ldapFilter -Properties enabled,AccountExpirationDate,memberof | Select Name,AccountExpirationDate,Enabled
    }
}| Select -Expand TotalSeconds | Measure-Object -Sum
```

Lets run those 2 commands 20 times each and see how long they take together. First get all users and filter for expired or disabled accounts. Second use ldap to only get accounts matching the same criteria as the previous.

```
Sum      : 13.0219249

Sum      : 1.6220821
```

As you can see the second query (ldap) took less than 2 seconds compare to the 13 that the first one took.

In short I'm tired and you should try to use and ldap query given your criteria and what appears to be a large org.

Comment: Your other question is ldap related so this shouldnt be to hard to grasp

Comment: Very cool! Can you comment on this observation I have? I'm guessing another main reason for how long this script is taking to run is due to the fact that it checks each active user record (over 20k of them). Is it appropriate to LDAP filter on WhenChanged=say since last week, to skip those and only process any user objects that have changed after a specified date? I'm assuming yes, but could use the LDAP filter syntax. Thanks again!

Comment: Edit, I will use (whenChanged>=20080812000000.0Z). Thanks

Comment: Hi Matt, I am curious, is this the same as your Math calculations? (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!accountExpires=0)(!accountExpires=9223372036854775807)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)). The reason I ask is because I only get a couple of results from your example and I can't understand exactly why that is. Thanks